# Create a raw file with windows context menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

**Windows 10/7:**

Wondering if it's possible to right click in any folder, from `New ->`  choosing `File` (I mean with no icon) and it let me type filename with extension. Then it become a html,css,txt file or whatever I typed as extension.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to change the title: "How can I create an empty file without extention with windows context menu?"

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a new file, it is just an empty file with extension, but that extension has no meaning until you actually put something inside the file.

By default *Hide extensions for known filetypes* is enabled. If you disable this setting, and you choose new textdocument, and then give it any name, such as MyAwesomeWebsite.htm it will then be a htm file.

So there's no need to create something in order to create raw files, because every file you make is a raw one. It just gives an extension for those of us who need to double click the file in order to open it with their default program.

To show extensions, do the following: Open an explorer window, go to the menu View, then at the right check `File name extensions`

Now, right-click, *New* > *Text document* and rename New Textdocument.txt to Whatever.anything and it will work as you request.

If you really want to add an entry to this New menu, which will save you the hastle of also editing the extension, then you can edit the registry and add it. It would only be interesting if you add this specific file on a daily basis and you are not using a text editor capable of creating your kind of files directly.

See here for the full instruction set:http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-remove-items-from-new-menu-in-windows/

The registry key is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.extension

From that extension, create a new key: `ShellNew` And give that a new `StringValue` with text `NullFile`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment. new users limitation!!!

But still no way for what i was looking. let' me say it better, right click and choose `new->**shortcut**`; what kind of file is created? nothing. I'm looking for something like that, except, not seeing a window to choose something. let me type a name and extension

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.